# Installed Apache 2.2 on Windows XP and didn't check "Install as service", how can I add apache to services?

Tags: windows-xp, apache-http-server, services

I Installed Apache 2.2 on Windows XP (with installer) and didn't check "Install as service". How can I add the Apache Windows Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#winsvc):

> You can install Apache as a service automatically during the
>   installation. If you chose to install for all users, the installation
>   will create an Apache service for you. If you specify to install for
>   yourself only, you can manually register Apache as a service after the
>   installation. You have to be a member of the Administrators group for
>   the service installation to succeed.
>
> Apache comes with a utility called the Apache Service Monitor. With it
>   you can see and manage the state of all installed Apache services on
>   any machine on your network. To be able to manage an Apache service
>   with the monitor, you have to first install the service (either
>   automatically via the installation or manually).
>
> You can install Apache as a Windows NT service as follows from the
>   command prompt at the Apache bin subdirectory:
>
> httpd.exe -k install